# Meta SO Upvote on Question: +5 or + 10?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, meta

I was told that each and every upvote on a question will add 5 points to the asker's reputation. But apparently this wasn't followed on here, meta SO.

Take a look at [my case for example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/3834?StartDate=2010-03-26&EndDate=2010-03-26).

Bug or feature?

Comment: We can't see your recent activity page.

Comment: @Chacha102, question updated with screenshot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Question rep was halved across the trilogy, except for Meta:

> ###[Important Reputation Rule Changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/)
> [...]
>
> - on Meta, the value of a question upvote will still be +10